# Slick Slider with 10 slides and 2 rows doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

I have a slick Slider on my page.
My Slider has 10 slides and 2 rows.
Follow by design I need to make Slider with 3 dots.
Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$('.slider').slick(
arrows: false,
dots: true,
SlidesToShow: 3,
SlidesToScroll: 2,
rows: 2,
);
```

Instead of SlidesToScroll: 2, it scroll 4 slides, and the last dot is not working.

Comment: What is `ja code`? JavaScript code? And what is your answerable programming question?